# Local Database Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7.1, local-database

I've created a local database for my Windows Phone 7 app and I created one table using the tutorial on msdn. I have a problem with a second table how do I add it ? When I make another class with Linq do I need to use the same datacontext class and just add another Table? I tried so many thing I tried to create it the same way I did the first table but nothing seems to work my app just crashes. Please help

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the program runs OK with one table (so you know your connection string and datacontext are OK for one table), then yes when you add a second table, you need to write an additional class with a [Table] attribute and you need to add a property to the datacontext.

```
    public class ATestDataContext : DataContext
    {
        public ATestDataContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
        {
        }

        public Table<FTable> FirstTable
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<FTable>();
            }
        }

        public Table<STable> SecondTable
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<STable>();
            }
        }
    }

[Table]
public class FTable : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyPropertyChanging
{...}

[Table]
public class STable : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyPropertyChanging
{...}
```

If you are looking to set up relationships between the tables, such as master-detail, then there are other things you need in your classes. One of the best examples I came across is here: http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Windows-Phone-Mango-Local-Database-mapping-and-database-operations